# Get specific category around city in Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api

I am using the Google Maps API and AutoComplete to make it easy for people to find restaurants around them. I have gotten this far but reading the documentation for it can be confusing. Is it possible to get a list of all the eating spots around Cupertino and if so how can it be achieved? Will I have to use SwiftyJson and or Alamofire in order to achieve this or does Google provides all the tools necessary to complete it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use  [`Google Places API`](https://developers.google.com/places/) to get a list of all eating spots around the area. Achieve it by including the parameter `types` values to filter place searches.

Below is a sample code snippet how to use Place types:

Search specific place in city by given type:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query= [Search place Name]+in+[City Name]&type=[Place Type]&sensor=true&key= [API Key]

You can use type `food` and `restaurant` like `type=food|restaurant`

for more information how to use Place Types, here's the link: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types